# FB user_link permission. Is it possible to get a link (even with limited validity) for user profile who is not my friend?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I have user_link permission for app, but I users profiles url's are working only when they are my friends on FB. Is it possible to get a link (even with limited validity) for user profile who is not my friend?

Comment: No. The description of the `link` field of the user object says, _“The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.”_ There is nothing else available.

Comment: @04FS - that seems to no longer be strictly true. Testing with test users, I have determined that the link will also work for two users who have at least one mutual friend, as of February 2019.

Comment: @JessieArr it might be that they lifted the restriction a little in the mean time.

Comment: @04FS This is no longer the case. The current Facebook reference docs mention nothing about this: "user_link
Requires App Review.

The user_link permission allows your app to access the Facebook profile URL of the person using your app.

Allowed Usage
Provide a way for someone who uses your app to visit that person's Facebook profile." See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: This is the description of user_link but actually facebook provides you with the link field. And as @04FS said the link field needs that you are friend of the user.
[docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)